# Can't subscribe because return value is AnonymousSubject instead of Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

Im facing the problem in Angular 4, trying to get the details from specific user when its clicked at 'user link profile'.

But I can't subscribe to my function ,because the return value of switchMap is AnonymousSubject instead of Observable:

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.getHero(+params.get('id')))
      .subscribe(hero => {
        this.hero = hero;
      })
  }
```

And here is the getHero function:

```
  getHero(id: number) {
     return this.getHeroes().find(hero=>hero.id===id);
  }
```

The getHeroes() function returns simple object of json data with details about heroes(id and name).

Thanks for any help/suggestion!

Comment: can you post your getHeroes method? Is it returning an array?

Comment: @LLai ye its simple return HeroList ,and that is an array of objects

Comment: switchMap expects you to return an observable, promise, array, or iterable. Your getHero method is returning an object. Try having it return an observable with the object value. `return Observable.of(this.getHeroes().find(hero=>hero.id===id));`

Comment: @LLai thank you a lot!!! That solve my lack of knowledge :)

Comment: glad I could help! I'll post an answer so it is easier for people to find in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switchMap expects you to return an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable. Your getHero method is returning an object. Try having it return an observable with the object value.

```
getHero(id: number) {
    let hero = this.getHeroes().find(hero=>hero.id===id);
    return Observable.of(hero);
}
```